# console.log shows object but when recursively calling function gets error

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

So here is my code:

```
function makeContent(jsonData){
    var aProperty, containerType, contentContainerName, containerIdentifier, containerComment, theContent ; 
        
    for(aProperty in jsonData){
        switch(aProperty){
            case "containerType": containerType = jsonData[aProperty];
            case "contentContainerName" : contentContainerName = jsonData[aProperty]; 
            case "containerComment" : containerComment = jsonData[aProperty];
            case "containerIdentifier" : containerIdentifier = jsonData[aProperty];
            case "itemContent" : theContent = jsonData[aProperty];
        }
    }


    if(theContent.hasOwnProperty){
        console.log(theContent);
        makeContent(theContent);
    }
```

I get this as my output:

> [Object] footer.js:59
>
> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'theContent.hasOwnProperty') footer.js:58

That just doesn't make sense to me because when I console.log(theContent) I get an object in it and it works fine. The error only occurs when I add the makeContent function as I am trying to recursively call the function. So I haven't added the return statement because of this error, should I do that?

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` somewhere, probably the end. (just a syntax thing, unrelated to your question)

Comment: `theContent` isn't always defined,

Comment: Also, [loop-switch sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using the conditional expression `if(theContent.hasOwnProperty)` to determine whether `theContent` is defined or not. The variable is declared atop the function and is only defined in the final `case`.

The surest way to check if a variable is defined is like so:

```
if (typeof theContent !== 'undefined`) { ... }
```

When the final `case` statement is not executed, `theContent` is not defined and attempting to access `hasOwnProperty` on an undefined value will result in the observed error.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That solved it. I thought Javascript did line by line and thought that theContent would be defined before it reached the function call.